# MySQL query wont execute using MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am making a small url shortener and everything works like a charm. However I want to create a "click" counter, so I can see how many clicks each link has gotten.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET["url"])) {
    $db = new mysqli("myhost", "myuser", "mypass", "mydb");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        throw new Exception("Connect failed: \n", $db->connect_error());
        exit();
    }

        $get = $db->real_escape_string($_GET["url"]);

        $result = $db->query("SELECT url_link FROM urls WHERE url_short = 
            '" . $get . "'
            ");

        $db->query("UPDATE urls SET url_hits = url_hits + 1 WHERE url_short =
            '" . $get . "'
            ");

        $data = $result->fetch_assoc();

        $redirect = $data[url_link];

        $db->close();

        header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');   
        header("Location: " . $redirect);  

} else {
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');   
    header("Location: home.php");  
}
```

What I expect to happen is that the second query will increment the number in my database by 1.

But nothing happens, the script does not fail or throw any errors, and if I run the query directly in MySQL, it works just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you in fact checking for errors? If not, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. As well as checking for errors for your query, which you are not doing; you're just assuming success before potential failure. `if (!$result) { throw new Exception($mysqli->error); }`

Comment: You can just use your querys like this: `$result = $db->query("SELECT url_link FROM urls WHERE url_short = '$get'");` and `$db->query("UPDATE urls SET url_hits = url_hits + 1 WHERE url_short = '$get'");` there is no need to append them like you do

Comment: I have error reporting turned on as a setting in my htaccess file. Still not any errors.

Comment: Error reporting setting is usually set in `php.ini` and not `.htaccess`

Comment: Not with my host. As I don't have access to their php.ini

Comment: Did the answer below work? Plus, try and doing `var_dump()` on the variables. You will see what's being passed through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from looking at your code:

```
$redirect = $data[url_link];
```

You need to have quotations around the array member you are calling, as such:

```
$redirect = $data["url_link"];
```

The way you have it currently should throw a syntax error. As mentioned in the comments, you likely have error reporting turned off.

Comment: This was actually the error. And not with the query, thanks ;)